# Is it possible to iterate a ConcurrentHashMap without creating new objects?

Tags: java, android, loops, optimization, hashmap

After profiling my android game, I notice an unusual amount of ConcurrentHashmaps generated during a simple iteration process that I call throughout the main game loop. The code is as follows

```
    public void checkIfStillNeedsToShowUI() {

      for (Map.Entry<String, GameUI> gameUIEntry : listOfUIObjects.entrySet()) {
        if(!gameUIEntry.getValue().isShowing()){//ignore what not showing
            continue;
        }
        final GameUI tmpGameUI = (gameUIEntry.getValue());
        if(!tmpGameUI.hasReasonForShowing()){
            continue;
        }

        if(tmpGameUI.reasonForShowing.checkReason()){
            tmpGameUI.setShowing(true);
        } else {
            tmpGameUI.setShowing(false);
        }

    }
}
```

and the results are as follows
[image: Profile 1]

[image: Profile 2]

[image: Profile 3]

Is this normal? or am I doing something wrong? I know that using the generic/enhanced for loop type results in an object being created in order to access it but I currently don't know another way to iterate a hashmap that would give me desired results.

Comment: Using `Map.forEach` instead of `for (entry : entrySet())` might well reduce the number of allocations, but you probably can't bring it to zero.

Comment: Funny the object is named `listOfUIObjects` but is actually a `Map`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman ill give it a try. Sadly ill have to up my min API to 24.

Comment: The answer is that, no, you are not doing anything wrong but it is not possible to iterate a ConcurrentHashMap without allocating objects. Sadly the JDK apis do often allocate objects. At my workplace we write zero allocation java but we do so by creating our own map implementations featuring reusable iterator instances that can be reset before use. If it's at all possible for you to use only a single thread to read/write then it'll be far easier to write your own single threaded map implementation that doesn't allocate. Good luck.

Comment: @AndrewS  it was once a list. a long long long time ago.

Comment: @junkie thanks for the advice. I'll see if using its possible to handle the map over a single thread.

Comment: See this library for fantastic single threaded fast non allocating collection implementations including maps: https://github.com/real-logic/agrona. Object to object map implementation here: https://github.com/real-logic/agrona/blob/master/agrona/src/main/java/org/agrona/collections/Object2ObjectHashMap.java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not instances of [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), they are instances of `MapEntry`.

If you mean `MapEntry` instances, the answer is no JDK create new instances of those objects during iteration of `ConcurrentHashMap` and it is inevitable when you are using `ConcurrentHashMap` you can see that in the `next` method in `EntityIterator` class inside `ConcurrentHashMap`. The problem is that to mange concurrency JDK store Objects of type `Node` and those objects are not considered to be exported as mentioned in Documentation in the source code:

> Key-value entry.  This class is never exported out as a user-mutable Map.Entry (i.e., one supporting setValue; see MapEntry below), but can be used for read-only traversals used in bulk tasks.  Subclasses of Node with a negative hash field are special, and contain null keys and values (but are never exported).  Otherwise, keys and vals are never null.

So `EntryIterator` class inside `ConcurrentHashMap` class converts this objects into `MapEntry` inside `next` method. If you are only using your map in single thread application you can use `HashMap` instead.

Comment: Using HashMap won't help. That also allocates objects on iteration. JDK collections generally speaking often do allocate which is why I personally don't use them.

Comment: @junkie Can you mention where in the `HashMap` source code those objects are allocated when `HashMap` is being iterated?

Comment: entrySet() creates an EntrySet and EntrySet creates a new EntryIterator on iteration. I think I see the distinction you're referring to. I'm talking about allocation in general. Even if it doesn't allocate on every iteration the fact that it allocates at all is still allocation. The collections I linked to above do not allocate at all. Any allocation can result in the heap filling up depending on frequency of calls. Though it may well be that the OP is trying to reduce allocation but perhaps not eliminate it completely.